# NullPointerException while trying to receive data from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

DataBase Structure
[image]

I am trying to get reference to Users from Chatlist. What i am trying to do is if a users is logged in he will see the users mentioned under is Uid in Chatlist node inside his recyclerview.

I am getting a the nullpointerexception in the following line

```
   DatabaseReference UserRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(chatlist.getId());
```

Exception

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:96)
    at com.shivam.chatapp2.Fragments.Chats.onCreateView(Chats.java:112)
```

MyCode

```
public class Chats extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;

private UserAdapter userAdapter;
private List<User> mUsers;

FirebaseUser fuser;
DatabaseReference reference;



FloatingActionButton profile, credentials;

ValueEventListener ChatListListener;
List<Chatlist> usersList;

private ChatsFragmentAdapter chatsFragmentAdapter;


public Chats() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);

    profile = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_edit_profile_pic);
    credentials = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_edit_name);
    FabAction();

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));



    fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    usersList = new ArrayList<>();

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist").child(fuser.getUid());
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            usersList.clear();
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Chatlist chatlist = snapshot.getValue(Chatlist.class);
                    usersList.add(chatlist);
                }
            }

            //chatList();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    Chatlist chatlist=new Chatlist();

    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference UserRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(chatlist.getId());
    UserRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                mUsers.add(user);

            }

            userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUsers, true);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



    return view;
}
```

Update

> Chatlist.java

```
    public class Chatlist {
    public String id;
    public String MessageCheck;

    public Chatlist() {
    }

    public Chatlist(String id) {
        this.id = id;

    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


}
```

> User.java

```
    public class User {

    private String id;
    private String First;
    private String EmailID;
    private String imageURL;
    private String status;

    public User(String id, String first, String emailID, String imageURL,String status) {
        this.id = id;
        this.First = first;
        this.EmailID = emailID;
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
        this.status=status;


    }

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String userid, String first_name, String eMail) {

    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirst() {
        return First;
    }

    public void setFirst(String first) {
        First = first;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }

    public String getEmailID() {
        return EmailID;
    }

    public void setEmailID(String emailID) {
        EmailID = emailID;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start listening to the `users` node from your first query of `chatlist` node:

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist").child(fuser.getUid());

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
usersList.clear();
if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
Chatlist chatlist = snapshot.getValue(Chatlist.class);
usersList.add(chatlist);

//start listening to users node here
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference UserRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(chatlist.getId());
UserRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
.....
....
....
}
....
....
```

**update**

Make sure this line is removed:

```
Chatlist chatlist=new Chatlist();
```

**update 2**

**don't do this inside your users query:**

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

mUsers.add(user);

}
```

**instead do this:**

```
User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
mUsers.add(user);
```

**update 3**

chatlist class:

```
public class Chatlist {
public String id;


public Chatlist(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public Chatlist(String id) {
    this.id = id;

}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}


}
```

users class:

```
public class User {

private String id;
private String First;
private String EmailId;
private String imageURL;
private String status;

public User(String id, String First, String EmailId, String imageURL,String status) {
    this.id = id;
    this.First = First;
    this.EmailId = EmailId;
    this.imageURL = imageURL;
    this.status=status;


}

public User() {
}

public User(String userid, String first_name, String eMail) {

}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirst() {
    return First;
}

public void setFirst(String first) {
    this.First = first;
}

public String getImageURL() {
    return imageURL;
}

public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
    this.imageURL = imageURL;
}

public String getEmailID() {
    return EmailId;
}

public void setEmailID(String emailID) {
    this.EmailId = emailID;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
```

}

Comment: you have to add the `UserRef.addListenerFor......` inside the onDataChange() method of the chatlist query.

Comment: I now get the error in following line    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);          and the error is    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.shivam.chatapp2.Model.User

Comment: I did that should i upload my modal class also??

Comment: I implemented your second update  and now its the following line    mUsers.add(user);     and the error is    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.shivam.chatapp2.Fragments.Chats$1$1.onDataChange(Chats.java:105)

Comment: Both model classes added

Comment: Okay look remake these classes, and make sure that the names of the variables are exaclty the same as the names of the keys in the database (capital and small letters must remain the same in both the classes and database).

Comment: Actually it was working fine until i created a separate Tab for Chatlist .I was able to see all users inside users node without any errors in a separate tab.I am now using same Adapter to see all the users and the users inside Chatlist .Should i create i separate adapter to show Chatlist items??

Comment: did you make the objects variables same name as your database?

Comment: I did you make the objects variables same name as in my database

Comment: Before this i was using another method to show Chatlist items and it was working fine but for that i had to download all the children inside users I can upload that method too if you want

Comment: use the classes i wrote them for you in my third update.

Comment: The error is still same after using your classes too

Comment: ahh make sure to name the class Users not User.

Comment: I changed here     User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                                    mUsers.add(user);   and now error has changed  to this       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.shivam.chatapp2.Fragments.Chats$1$1.onDataChange(Chats.java:112)

Comment: I came up with a solution in my update 2 but its only a half solution for this there should be fixed no. of users  under userid of current user in Chatlist